# Why can we write a for loop without Curly Brackets in methods out of main function

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, curly-braces

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BNil.png)

Why can we write a for loop without Curly Brackets in methods out of main function

Comment: Why can we ? Because that are the rules, you can write block without bracket if they contain one instruction

Comment: Because that's the syntax that the language designers chose.  I believe they did that, to make it similar to C and C++.  The fact that a `for` loop without braces is legal doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: Just to make it easier for you to use.

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 2):

For statement requires a single statement that will be executed on each iteration.

```java
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    <statement>
```

It can be simple statement, for example, `System.out.println("loop iteration");`. If you need to execute multiple statements for each iteration than you have to use *compound statement*, in other words, you have to enclose list of your statements into curly brackets.

And, of course, this has nothing to do with main function.